# First 100s place without a prime

Tags: prime-numbers

What is the first $100$'s place without a prime?

$700$ -> primes: $701, 709, 719$, etc.

$103900$ -> primes: $103951, 103963, 103967, 103969, 103979$, etc.

But at some point, there are gaps of hundreds and thousands between prime numbers, so what is the first gap that spans an entire hundred's place?

Comment: http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html#MainTable

Comment: http://oeis.org/A136295

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no prime number between $1,671,800$ and $1,671,900$, and this is the first such gap.

SageMath script:

```
P = Primes()
n = 0
while P.next(n * 100) - (n * 100) < 100:
    n += 1
print n * 100 // prints 1671800
```

Comment: According to this table (http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html#MainTable), that is not the first prime gap $\geq 101$.

Comment: I think he just found out the first gap which is equal to exactly 100 places.

Comment: As asked, it is the first gap between consecutive multiples of 100.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I checked and the two primes are 1671781 and 1671907. All of the other lesser primes that have >100 difference between them fall on consecutive 100s.

Comment: @ManishKundu: No, Zev's gap is within a 125-gap starting at 1671782. It is just the first one between $100n$ and $100(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a possible formula for finding gaps. You just get your answer by using some computer code.

The answer is, from the number 370262, there are at least 100 non-prime numbers continuously.

And if you meant to ask the first gap between two consecutive multiples of hundred, then it's from 1671800 till 1671900.

Comment: Yes there is. You can find a gap of size $n-1$ in every sequence: $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Python 3 code that finds all the solutions < 5000000. Un-comment the `break` statement if you just want the first solution. This script will also run on Python 2, but it will use less RAM if you change `range` to `xrange`.

```
num = 5000000
sieve = num//2 * [True]
for i in range(3, int(num**0.5) + 1, 2):
    if sieve[i//2]:
        sieve[i*i//2::i] = (1 + (num - i*i - 1) // (2*i)) * [False]
for j in range(0, num // 2, 50):
    if not any(sieve[j:j+50]):
        print(2*j)
        #break
```

#### output

```
1671800
2637800
3117300
3933600
4640600
4652400
```

This code runs in less than one second on my ancient 2GHz 32 bit machine.

It uses a Sieve of Eratosthenes to find odd primes. The sieve code was derived from [code by Robert William Hanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/4014959).