# Something strange about prime gaps and $p-q =999999999999182774421592902$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Coming across the post [*First 100s place without a prime*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592474/first-100s-place-without-a-prime), I went to the informative link "[*First occurrence prime gaps*](http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html#MainTable)" suggested by Jack D'Aurizio. The main list of $999$ prime $p$  covers the smallest $p$ for each *even* gap $\leq1998$.

**I.** But I noticed something a bit strange. Let $p,q$ be primes in the list.

**Example 1**. Given $p,q$ such that the next prime is $p+1886$ and $q+1902$,

$$p=4521777371028957272039263763\\q=3521777371029774497617670861\\p-q =999999999999182774421592902$$

**Example 2**. Given $p,q$ such that the next prime is $p+1896$ and $q+1968$,

$$p=17817006514740891827868262213 \\q=16817006514738017659250207459 \\p-q =1000000000002874168618054754$$

**Example 3**. Given $p,q$ such that the next prime is $p+1774$ and $q+1818$,

$$p=161023337028376633976274427 \\q=361023337029228675738125911\\|p-q| =200000000000852041761851484$$

and so on. Given two *random* primes $p_1,p_2$ of about the same size *but not in the list*, what are the odds that their difference will be similar to the examples above? But $p,q$ are ***NOT*** random: they are the smallest primes for two given gaps.

Quite a ***lot*** of the $999$ primes in the list can be paired in such a manner, if they are about the same size. I have chosen only the most spectacular.

> **Q1:** What is the reason for such behavior, the zeros and nines?

---

**II.** Some primes in the list do need not a difference, the zeros are ***in*** the prime.

$$\begin{array}{|c|l|} 
\hline
\text{Gap} & \hskip0.9in \text{Prime}\\
\hline
1832 & {7500230000000254312587886349}\\
1836 & {7500230000004410741095419811}\\
1838 & 7051230000020674054592576303\\
1846 & {7500230000005824418875087691}\\
1848 & 2644230000031218882264673171\\
1856 & 5851230000021967795781669357\\
1882 & 8511230000017373935165665319\\
1884 & 5844230000028765302725127593\\
1888 & {7500230000005019060037933673}\\
1920 & 2844230000030892453360363713\\
1944 & 3044230000030128405583745033\\
1980 & 8051230000019922137852468729\\
1982 & {7500230000011523034496281371}\\
1996 & 85982514713000000005643994785767\\
\hline\end{array}$$

> **Q2:** What is the reason for that as well?

Comment: What happens if you change from base ten? Can you still pair them up? (Obviously not the same pairs)

Comment: @Arthur: I think the phenomenon will still exist. For example,$$750023\times10^{22}+n$$ is in the list for five $n$ and, regardless of base, the difference of any two will yield zeros. (Albeit, since they are leading zeros, will vanish.)

Comment: In the [Notes](http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html#Notes), he writes "No gap exceeding 1510 has been definitively established as a first occurrence; larger gaps included in these lists are instead first known occurrence prime gaps." It's an artefact of _where_ people looked for prime gaps.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah. Let me look at the gaps 1100-1500 which involve primes with 18-19 digits. Give me several minutes with my _Mathematica_.

Comment: It's not that. The $p,q$ for the smallest *known* prime gaps of $1458$ and $1470$ are a little smaller than $10^{23}$. The limit up to which all prime gaps are known is $10^{19}$ now. There's a *lot* of space in between to have a prime gap of $1458$ or $1470$ earlier. It's not (yet) feasible to search that completely. The smallest occurrence of many of those prime gaps will remain unknown for many years.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I searched the digits of pi and the phenomenon ***was*** there in weak form. So it was not purely an artifact of the prime hunters method, but apparently also an artifact of my own search method. I'll summarize it as a tentative answer.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Daniel Fischer, the phenomenon is most probably an artifact (and in two ways). First, from ***where*** people looked for prime gaps. Second, it seems also an artifact of my search method. For example, I found

$$p−q=999999999999182774421592902\tag1$$

by letting *Mathematica* look at about 120 $28$-digit numbers in the list. With $n=120$, there are $n(n+1)/2 = 7260$ pairs. Since it turns out the 120 $p,q$ had "pre-determined" parameters, then the search was bound to find relationships such as above.

---

For a truly random list, I used consecutive digits of $\pi-3$ as 120 $18$-digit blocks $B_n$,

$$141592653589793238,\\ 462643383279502884,\\ 197169399375105820,\\ \vdots$$

and Mathematica found,

$$B_{99} =601653466804988627\\
B_{104} =984896084128488626\\
|B_{99}-B_{104}| = 3832426173234\color{blue}{99999}$$

and,

$$B_{49} =752886587533208381\\
B_{64} =727855889075098381\\
B_{49}-B_{64} = 2503069845811\color{blue}{0000}$$

Not as impressive as $(1)$, but that $p,q$ had the advantage of a related starting point.